# Why does Bonaparte and Chapek only take away one of the twin instead of both of them?

Tags: monster

Both of them seems to think johan and anna are equally perfect so why not grab both of them and bring them to the red rose mansion and put them in seperate place so they cannot meet with each other ? Doesn't the more " monster " they have the better

Thanks in advance